# Possible to create an implicit cast for an anonymous type to a dictionary?

Tags: c#, syntax, anonymous-types

I wrote a method like this:

```
using AttrDict = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>;
using IAttrDict = System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, object>>;

static string HtmlTag(string tagName, string content = null, IAttrDict attrs = null)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder("<");
    sb.Append(tagName);
    if(attrs != null)
        foreach (var attr in attrs)
            sb.AppendFormat(" {0}=\"{1}\"", attr.Key, attr.Value.ToString().EscapeQuotes());
    if (content != null) sb.AppendFormat(">{0}</{1}>", content, tagName);
    else sb.Append(" />");
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Which you can call like

```
HtmlTag("div", "hello world", new AttrDict{{"class","green"}});
```

Not too bad. But what if I wanted to allow users to pass an anonymous type in place of the dict? Like

```
HtmlTag("div", "hello world", new {@class="green"});
```

Even better! I could write the overload easily, but the problem is I'm going to have about 50 functions like this, I don't want to overload each one of them. I was hoping I could just write an implicit cast to do the work for me...

```
public class AttrDict : Dictionary<string, object>
{
    public static implicit operator AttrDict(object obj)
    {
        // conversion from anonymous type to AttrDict here
    }
}
```

But C# simply won't allow it:

> user-defined conversions to or from a base class are not allowed

So what can I do?

Comment: use reflection to query what members and values are set on your anonymous object

Comment: @Pauli: Yes, I know how to do that bit, the question was about how to accept *either* type (anonymous, or a dict).

Comment: ah... yeah, for that you have to use the lowest common denominator (object), which already has been mentioned :)

Comment: @Pauli: Yeah..was hoping I could just type-cast it though instead of accepting a generic object so it's more clear about what data type is accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do what you want directly.  Like the ASP.NET MVC helper methods, you should probably go the other way.  `attrs` should just be of type `object`.  Then within the body of the method, you can handle it as either an anonymous type or a dictionary depending on its runtime type.

Comment: Heh... I guess everything will get filtered through that HtmlTag function anyway, so..yeah, this should work. Silly me.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an extension-method that uses reflection to do the conversion you want. This would look something like:

```
public static class AttrDictX
{
    public static AttrDict ToAttrDict(this object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("obj");

        var ans = new AttrDict();

        foreach (var prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if (prop.CanRead)
                ans.Add(prop.Name, prop.GetValue(obj, null));
        }

        return ans;
    }
}
```

Then the call-site will either:

1. Contain a `.ToAttrDict()` call.
2. (or) Look unchanged if you can provide an overload to the `HtmlTag` method that takes an `object` instead and does the conversion internally.

The second option is particularly desirable if you don't like extensions on `object`, which some people (not me) consider bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

## My Solution

```
static string EscapeQuotes(this string str)
{
    return str.Replace("\"", "\\\"");
}

static IAttrDict ToDictionary(this object obj)
{
    return obj.GetType().GetProperties().Where(prop => prop.CanRead).ToDictionary(prop => prop.Name, prop => prop.GetValue(obj, null));
}

static string HtmlTag(string tagName, string content = null, object attrs = null)
{
    IAttrDict attrDict = attrs != null ? attrs is IAttrDict ? (IAttrDict)attrs : attrs.ToDictionary() : null;

    var sb = new StringBuilder("<");
    sb.Append(tagName);
    if(attrDict != null)
        foreach (var attr in attrDict)
            sb.AppendFormat(" {0}=\"{1}\"", attr.Key, attr.Value.ToString().EscapeQuotes());
    if (content != null) sb.AppendFormat(">{0}</{1}>", content, tagName);
    else sb.Append(" />");
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: The only reason I didn't do it your way (LINQ) is that you had subclassed `Dictionary<,>` to create `AttrDict`; and I expected that you wanted the output to be of that type.

Comment: @Ani: I was only trying to subclass it so that I could add an implicit operator -- it won't let me add an operator on a type I didn't define.